# Time module and function (from time import time) don‘t work

Tags: python

I have an exercise to calculate how much time a sequence search takes.

I imported time function from time module and used it inside seq_search function.

But, after compiling it, no time is displayed.

Suppose that mistake is, probably in position of line with start = time() or end = time().

Hope, somebody knows the solution for this.

```
from time import time
import random

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def seq_search(a, x):
    start = time()         # start calculating time from here
    n = len(a)
    i = 0
    while (i < n):
        if(a[i] == x):
            return i
        else:
            i = i + 1
    end = time()           # stop here
    print("Lasted time: ", end-start) # print calculated time
    return -1

print(seq_search(a, 3))
```

Comment: Two times *do* get displayed.

Comment: Could you be more concrete?

Comment: Since `3` is only the third number in `a`, the first two iterations of the while loop do get to the printing of time.

Comment: Understand that, but how manage to display this end - start time?

Comment: It has to do something with the indentation. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `end = time()` and `print` are inside your while loop.

However, the function is returning the value of `i`, if it is equal to `x`, before it gets to the `end` and `print` statements.

Comment: Even, with moving end = time() and print outside while loop I get no time display.

Comment: the print must come before `return`. When you return from a function the rest of the function is never executed.

Comment: I would just store the value of `i` using a `break` inside of the while loop. Then instead of printing, do a `return "Lasted time: " + str(end-start)`